# How can I replace gcc with g++-11 for C++20 when running cmake

Tags: gcc, networking, cmake, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Specs:

- WSL, ubuntu 22.04
- cmake version 3.25.2
- g++ version: 11.4.0
- gcc version: 11.4.0

I was doing lab0 of CS144, Spring 2023 of Stanford when I got stuck at the very beginning. When I ran `cmake --build build`, I got the following error message:

```
 error: invalid return type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} of ‘constexpr’ function ‘static constexpr std::string ExpectationViolation::boolstr(bool)’
   16 |   static constexpr std::string boolstr( bool b ) { return b ? "true" : "false"; }
```

I found out on the Internet that this was because `constexpr std::string` was introduced in C++ 20 and what I had on my wsl was gcc-11 and g++-11, and gcc-11 only supports some experimental features of C++ 20. So I intend to set the default compiler of Cmake to g++. However, I keep getting the same error message.

i have tried installing g++-12:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Sep 27 21:24 /usr/bin/g++ -> /etc/alternatives/g++*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 13 15:52 /usr/bin/g++-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 13 15:33 /usr/bin/g++-12 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-12*
 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Sep 27 21:46 /usr/bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 13 15:52 /usr/bin/gcc-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 13 15:33 /usr/bin/gcc-12 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  5  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May 13 15:52 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May 13 15:33 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-12 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-12*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  5  2021 /usr/bin/gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May 13 15:52 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-11 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May 13 15:33 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-...
```

It didn't work. Then i tried building a soft link:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
There is only one alternative in link group gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc): /usr/bin/g++-11
Nothing to configure.

sudo update-alternatives --config g++
There is only one alternative in link group g++ (providing /usr/bin/g++): /usr/bin/g++-11
Nothing to configure.
```

It still did not work. I am now clueless.

Comment: How did you install GCC 12? If you bypassed the package manager, it will not be listed as an alternative. You need to add it yourself. But that would be a question of its own.

Comment: i think i ran `sudo apt-get gcc-12`. and i did add it as an alternative! i did quite some changes last night bc i'm a total newbie. but now it works out! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and non-invasive way to make CMake use another C++ compiler is to set the `CXX` environment variable:

As the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXX.html) explains, the result is cached so you need to delete `CMakeCache.txt` (or your whole build directory) before running the lines above to make the changes apply.

The commands to run might look like this:

```bash
rm -rf build
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-12
cmake -S . -B build
```

Caching may also be the reason why your previous attempts didn't work out.

BTW, the steps to set a C compiler are the same, only the `CC` environment variable is to be used.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that caching really was the reason. But deleting the whole build dir didn't work either, so I tried (backing up and) deleting the CMakeList.txt and did `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-12`. After this I pasted the orginal CMakeList.txt back and ran `cmake -S . -B build`, and this time it works out!

Comment: That doesn't sound as if it could have worked. While updating the time stamp of `CMakeLists.txt` will cause CMake to re-generate the build system, it will not empty or renew the cache. For now, it's good you can carry on with your project.

Comment: @Overstacked I realized you might have run your commands in the wrong order. My original answer was ambiguous about it. I edited to make things clear.

Comment: thank you for updating the answers. now that i think about it it's much clearer. i use the following to set priorities now:`sudo update-alternatives --config gcc/++`, `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-12 10`, `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 20`,
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-12 10`,
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 20`,`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30`, `sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc` ... it works fine

Answer (score 0):

gcc/g++ is the compiler and 11.4.0 is the compiler's version not the language's

c++ 20 is a c++ standard

the two things are different

you need to change the cmake (CMakeLists.txt) to use different c++ standard
something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

or alternatively dont use those features